# Regular Expression for the date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I need a regular expression for validating date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ using xsd.
Could you please help me to get the regex pattern?

Comment: What have you tried so far? People on SO are much more likely to answer your problem when they see you have put some effort in and aren't just going to write your code for you!

Comment: I think that you should use xs:dateTime [reference here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp), if you add a pattern you spend effort to validate the XMLs.

Comment: I have created a xsd file which will validate the XML input file using LINQ.<xs:simpleType><xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime"> <xs:pattern value="(?n:^(?=\d)((?<day>31(?!(.0?[2469]|11))|30(?!.0?2)|29(?(.0?2)(?=.{3,4}(19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))|0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?<sep>[/.-])(?<month>0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?<year>(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(?<time>([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1})$)"/> </xs:restriction></xs:simpleType> However the regex pattern I am using to validate date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ is not working as expected. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This regex will validate only datetime, not only date or only time. Dates are in the DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm format and validated for months, number of days in a month and leap years (29/2) Date field can be separated by matched periods(.), dashes(-) or forward slashes(/). Year range 1900-9999 Time is in 24 hour military format (HH:mm:SS), from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59, where hours and minutes fields are required, including leading 0 for hours less than 10. Datetime is the above date and time formats separated by a space, with the date first (DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm) !IMPORTANT NOTE: your regex engine must support lookaheads and named groups to use this expression

```
(?n:^(?=\d)((?<day>31(?!(.0?[2469]|11))|30(?!.0?2)|29(?(.0?2)(?=.{3,4}(19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))|0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(?<sep>[/.-])(?<month>0?[1-9]|1[012])\2(?<year>(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2})(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(?<time>([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1})$)
```

Comment: Specify your source for this answer, It is just a copy paste from [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=mm%2Fdd%2Fyyyy&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&p=2)

Comment: Hi, I get an error message while using the above regex pattern. Please refer the error below. Not well formed: The value of the attribute "value" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<'character. Please suggest.